# How do I programmatically change the user ID in a order?

Tags: 8, users, commerce

I programmatically created a user using the following code.

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Helper function to create a new user.
 */
function create_new_user() {
  $user = User::create();
  $user->setPassword('<password>');
  $user->enforceIsNew();
  $user->setEmail('<email>');
  $user->setUsername('<username>');
  $user->save();
  drupal_set_message("User with uid " . $user->id() . " saved!\n");
}
```

Now I need to set the ID of the created user into an order.

I've loaded the order using the following code.

```
$ord_id = 10;
$order = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->load($ord_id);
```

I want to update the user ID of this order. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
$order->setCustomer($user)->save();
```

Or if you only have the user ID and don't want to load the account object:

```
$order->set('uid', $uid);
$order->save();
```